# Dynamic Table Name with Sequelize in Node JS

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have a Keycloak Database for my users. Everytime a new user gets added in this database, I need to add a new table to my MySQL Database like this

```
"timelogs_" + userId
```

Is there any possibility to realize this with sequelize to add this table with a Model?

Thank you!

Comment: This is bad practice.

Comment: @NilankaManoj do you know a practice how I can do this?
I'm a very new programmer :D

Comment: I added it as an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create tables for each user is a bad practice. You should create **timelogs** table with **user_id** attribute where refer to a user's **id** in the **user** table.

So:

- user table columns: id,user_name,...
- timelog table columns: id, user_id, time, ...

timelog.user_id refers to user.id as foreign key

In sequalize:

You can have **timelogs** attribute in model user.

Comment: Ok I'll try it this way. Thank you very much :)

Comment: So is it possible to use the sequelize function
```
User.hasMany('Timelogs')
```

Comment: yeah. you got it

Comment: Ok, then finally I got it. Thank you very much :D